# react function component inside class component, is a valid component ? What is the difference?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to return a ***function component*** after the condition is checked within a ***class component***. Here is my code:

```
 class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props.warn;
  }

   function WarningBanner() {
    if (this.state == false) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="warning">
        Warning!
      </div>
    );
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <WarningBanner />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page warn={true}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Is a ***function component*** inside a ***class component*** considered a valid ***component*** ? Or is there a another way to define a ***function component*** inside a ***class component***?

> What is the difference between a ***function component*** inside ***class component*** or a ***function component*** outside a ***class component*** ?

I have also tried doing this:

```
<WarningBanner warn = {this.state}/>
```

And

```
function WarningBanner(warning) {
    if (warning.warn == false) {
      return null;
    }
    return (<div className="warning">Warning!</div>);
  }
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/skeitnepal/pen/jOPMaLe?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, function compoment inside the class component is valid and it is possible to share state of main component too and their is no difference in ***function component*** and ***function component*** inside ***class component*** as individial component.

Problem here is entirely related to javascript rather than react. Here is the right code:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: props.warn};
    this.warning = this.WarningBanner.bind(this);
  }
  WarningBanner() {
    if (this.state.value == false) { 
      return null;
    }
    return (<div className="warning">Warning!</div>);
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>{this.warning()}</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Page warn={true}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

***Problem 1:*** *function keyword can not be defined inside javascript class since class itself supposed to act like a function.*

***Problem 2:*** *New functions in javascript class needs to be 'bind' and access by 'this.warning' variable.*

I hope it will be useful for someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like...

```
    class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props.warn;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.warn && <div className="warning">Warning!</div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page warn={true}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Where `{this.props.warn && <div className="warning">Warning!</div>}` will evaluate if the condition is true and, if so, render the component.

If you wanted to make a more complex functional component, I would suggest creating it outside of your stateful component like this...

```
const Warning = () => {
  return (<div className="warning">Warning!</div>);
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = props.warn;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.warn && <Warning />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page warn={true}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I would recommend this method to comply with React best practices, as outside of codepen you would have different files for different components.

Here's a pen to illustrate: https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/zYGKRNa

hope this helps!

Comment: You could also render different components based on conditions, for example `this.state.warn ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />`

Comment: However, is it possible to (at all) to do somthing like that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you please elaborate?

Comment: is functional component inside a class component is a valid component?

Comment: You could put the component in the `Render` function, outside the `return()` function and it would also work. I'd always opt for the first method in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think nesting the definition of components like that is idiomatic.

Data can be shared between components using properties.

You can show or hide the banner using a conditional (here, I use the `&&` operator) in your `Page` component like so:

```js
function WarningBanner({message}) {
    return (<div className="warning">Warning!</div>)
} 

class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.showWarning && <WarningBanner /> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Page showWarning={true} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}
.warning {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;

  font-size: 14pt;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```